# Remove function for an avl tree not working

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

The variables in the scrut are part of the project objectives, the only important is the "codigo" that works as the value that is searched for in the tree,direita is right, esquerda is left, and pai is father, these are the only ones that matters in the removing process, the function is the one suposed to remove and balance the tree, but it doesnt do anything when i try to remove any entry, can someone tell me whats wrong please? if you need the rest of the code and the main file just ask , the struct is in an header file and the function in a .c file "VrotacaoRR or LL" are the functions that rotate the values to balance VabpAltura measures the height of the tree

Note: there`s no error, it just doesnt work

I've cheked the rotations, compared with the example code i found, but instead of an int i have to use a string

```
typedef struct ABP1
{
char codigo[5]; char descricao[5];
int preco, dataInicio, dataFim, bal;
struct ABP1* direita;
struct ABP1* esquerda;
struct ABP1* pai;

}*viagens;

void removerViagem(viagens apt, char codigo[5])
{
char aux=NULL;
viagens v;

if (apt == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

if (strcmp(apt->codigo, codigo)<0)
{
    removerViagem((apt->esquerda), codigo);
    apt->bal = VabpAltura(apt->esquerda) - VabpAltura(apt->direita);

    if (apt->bal == -2)
    {
        if (apt->direita->bal != 1)
        {
            apt = VrotacaoRR(apt);
        }
        else if (apt->direita->bal == 1)
        {
            apt->direita = VrotacaoLL(apt->direita);
            apt = VrotacaoRR(apt);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if (strcmp(codigo, apt->codigo)>0)
    {
        removerViagem(apt->direita, codigo);
        apt->bal = VabpAltura(apt->esquerda) - VabpAltura(apt->direita);
        if (apt->bal == 2)
        {
            if (apt->esquerda->bal != -1)
            {
                apt = VrotacaoLL(apt);
            }
            else if (apt->esquerda->bal == -1)
            {
                apt->esquerda = VrotacaoRR(apt->esquerda);
                apt = VrotacaoLL(apt);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (strcmp(apt->codigo,codigo)==0)
        {
            if (apt->esquerda == NULL && apt->direita == NULL)
            {
                free(apt);
                apt = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((apt->esquerda == NULL && apt->direita != NULL) || apt->bal == -1)
                {
                    v = apt->direita;
                    while (v->esquerda != NULL)
                    {
                        v = v->esquerda;
                    }
                    strcpy(aux, v->codigo);
                    removerViagem(apt, v->codigo);
                    strcpy(apt->codigo,codigo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to learn how to debug the program. Step through the program with the debugger and see where it will diverge from the expected path.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add print statements after every branch.  That way you will know how the logic flow works (or doesn't). Start will small sample trees, zero, one, two nodes, then work your way up once those work.

Comment: Thank you, ill try to do that